# Iterate a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration

I want to loop a JavaScript object structure to find some data, and when I find this data, break out of the loop.

Something like [pseudo-code]:

```
obj = {  /*All the structure*/ };
while (i < lenght of obj structure) or (the data I was looking for wasn't found){
  //(...)
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the length of this structure and I can't iterate it with a `while`.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: This is very expensive, since my object is very big

Comment: Use `break`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break. You can only use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you do, try this:

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

Data is your json object.